# How can I cross check a data frame if all possible combinations on it exist in another data frame of reference in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames.

The first one that contain all the possible combinations with their corresponding value and looks like this :

| first | second | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | Beta | 10 |
| Alpha | Corn | 20 |
| Alpha | Desk | 30 |
| Beta | Corn | 40 |
| Betea | Desk | 50 |
| Corn | Desk | 60 |
| Hat | Ian | 70 |

The second one that comes from the production line has two columns the date column  that has grouped all the variables corresponding to their date and are concatenated :

| date | var |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A |
| 2022-02-01 | Beta,Corn,Fanta,Epsilon,George,Hat,Ian |

I want to find all the combinations in the second data frame and to see if they match with any combinations in the first data frame.If a variable stands alone in the second data frame as Alpha in 2022-01-01 to give me the 0 and otherwise the value of the combination.

Ideally I want the resulted data frame to look like this :

| date | comb | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | Alpha | 0 |
| 2022-02-01 | Beta,Corn | 40 |
| 2022-02-01 | Hat,Ian | 70 |

How can I do this in R using dplyr ?

```
library(tidyverse)
first = c("Alpha","Alpha","Alpha","Beta","Beta","Corn","Hat")
second = c("Beta","Corn","Desk","Corn","Desk","Desk","Ian")
val = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)
df1 = tibble(first,second,val);df1
date = c(as.Date("2022-01-01"),as.Date("2022-02-01"))
var = c("Alpha","Beta,Corn,Fanta,Epsilon,George,Hat,Ian")
df2  = tibble(date,var);df2
```

Comment: @akrun is Hat I edited my OP.Yes is grouped by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to split the rows of the 'df2' based on the 'var' column delimiter `,` with `separate_rows`, grouped by 'date', do a `combn`ation of the 'var's create the `first`, `second` columns in a `tibble` from the pairwise combinations, `unnest` the `list` columns, do a join with the 'df1' dataset, and another join with 'df2' (in case some dates are lost because of no matches), and `unite` the 'first', 'second' to create the `combn` after `coalesce`ing the 'first' with the 'var'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
  separate_rows(var) %>%
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(var = if(length(var) > 1) list(combn(var, 2,  \(x) 
   tibble(first = x[1], second = x[2]), simplify = FALSE) %>% 
    bind_rows) else 
  list(tibble(first = var, second = var)) ) %>% 
 unnest(var) %>%
 inner_join(df1, by = c("first", "second")) %>% 
 full_join(df2, by = "date") %>% 
 mutate(first = coalesce(first, var)) %>%
  unite(combn, first, second, sep = ", ") %>% 
 select(-var)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  date       combn        val
  <date>     <chr>      <dbl>
1 2022-02-01 Beta, Corn    40
2 2022-02-01 Hat, Ian      70
3 2022-01-01 Alpha, NA     NA
```